# my output is not displaying on the browser console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, use-state

I am creating a form with some handling functions.

This is my functions that handle the events.

```
const [name, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [age, setAge] = useState("");

  const handleNameChange = (event) => {
    setUsername(event.target.value);
  };
  const handleAgeChange = (event) => {
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };
  const submitFormHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(name,age);
  };
```

I use styled component to style my Form tag.
import styled from "styled-components";

```
const Forms = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  & label {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 15px;
  }

  & input {
    width: 40%;
    height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  & button {
    margin: 10px;
  }
`;
```

This is my form.

```
<Forms onSubmit={submitFormHandler}>
      <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
      <input id="username" type="text" onChange={handleNameChange} />

      <label htmlFor="age">Age(Years)</label>
      <input id="age" type="number" onChange={handleAgeChange}/>

      <button type="submit">Add User</button>
</Forms>
```

I use styled components to style the `<Form>` tag. So , my problem is after I clicked the submit button, I have error on the onSubmit event handler function where name and age of the user input is not displaying on the browser console.

[This is the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmTnR.png)

After I clicked the submit button, the values are not displaying on the browser console

Comment: What kind of error do you have?

Comment: @HasanMobarak in my submitHandler function I output the values but it is not displaying on the browser console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Forms` component is a styled `<div>`.

Only `<form>` elements emit a [*submit* event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event). Use this instead...

```js
const Forms = styled.form`
  etc
`;
```

You're also missing the `value` bindings in your `<input>` elements

```html
<input
  id="username"
  type="text"
  value={name}
  onChange={handleNameChange}
/>

<input
  id="age"
  type="number"
  value={age}
  onChange={handleAgeChange}
/>
```

See [Controlled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)